# Keyboard shortcuts don't work in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, shortcut

I have a winform application written in `C#` that was developed under `Windows 7`. Many of the `menu commands have keyboard shortcuts` which are defined in the `control properties` When I run this application on a `Windows 8` system, `none of the shortcut keys work`, in fact I get what sounds like the `default beep`, as if I am doing something wrong. Some other aspects of the program aren't functioning quite correctly also, but this is something I just expect to work and have no idea how I would work around this problem. Thanks in advance for any advice on how to fix this problem.

Gary

It's all designer generated:

```
this.saveConfigurationToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.S)));
```

Comment: Can you show a current snippet of your code? for example does the current code check anything like this `if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Control)` if the user were to press the `CTRL Key`

Comment: It's all designer generated:   this.saveConfigurationToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = ((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)((System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control | System.Windows.Forms.Keys.S)));

Comment: can you post your code under your original question, just click on the edit link to post / format your code snippet.